# has_many with class_name in polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

In my new Rails Project I need access to my old database. So I created some legacy Models.
I have a polymorphic assocation between photos and comments(commentable_id and commentable_type)

When I call

> Legacy::Photo.last.comments

it doesn't work because the commentable_type is 'Photo' and not 'LegcayPhoto'.

```
SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_id" = $1 AND "comments"."commentable_type" = $2  [["commentable_id", 123], ["commentable_type", "Legacy::Photo"]]
```

legacy/photo.rb

```
module Legacy
  class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection "legacy_#{Rails.env}"
    belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'Legacy::User' #works fine
    has_many :comments, :class_name => 'Legacy::Comment', :as => :commentable
  end
end
```

legacy/comment.rb

```
module Legacy
  class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection "legacy_#{Rails.env}"
    #?? belongs_to :commentable,  :polymorphic => true
  end
end
```

I also have a problem in legacy/comments.rb. 
Is there a way to add the namespace for belongs_to :commentable,  :polymorphic => true ?

Comment: In the Comment model, it should be belongs_to :photo, :class_name => Legacy::Photo

Comment: But then its no longer polymorphic.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps not the most ideal approach, but instead of building the `has_many` association, you can now easily define a method that returns an ActiveRecord query which imitates what the `has_many` returns:

```
module Legacy
  class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection "legacy_#{Rails.env}"
    belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'Legacy::User' #works fine

    def comments
      Comment.where("commentable_type='LegacyPhoto' AND commentable_id=?", self.id)
    end
  end
end
```

Now, you can still say things like:

```
Legacy::Photo.comments.where(created_at > 1.day.ago)
```

and it will still work.